# The sum of the closest record to the desired value

Tags: c#, algorithm, sum, expression

How do I write that method has the following results, how can i create Filter metod? The sum of the closest record to the desired value

```
class Program
{
public Program()
{
    List<item> items = new List<item>() 
    {
        new item () { Id = 11 , Value = 100},
        new item () { Id = 12 , Value = 300},
        new item () { Id = 13 , Value = 10},
        new item () { Id = 14 , Value = 20},
        new item () { Id = 15 , Value = 200},
        new item () { Id = 16 , Value = 600},
        new item () { Id = 17 , Value = 7},
        new item () { Id = 18 , Value = 3},
        new item () { Id = 19 , Value = 3},
        new item () { Id = 20 , Value = 2},
        new item () { Id = 21 , Value = 70},
        new item () { Id = 22 , Value = 200},
        new item () { Id = 23 , Value = 300},
        new item () { Id = 24 , Value = 250},
        new item () { Id = 25 , Value = 900},
        new item () { Id = 26 , Value = 700},
        new item () { Id = 27 , Value = 400},
    };

    var list_1 = items.Filter(1000);    //expect id : 11,12,16
    var list_2 = items.Filter(25);      //expect id : 13,17,18,19,20
    var list_3 = items.Filter(400);     //expect id : 11,12
    var list_4 = items.Filter(1935);    //expect id : 11,12,13,14,15,16,18,20,25
    var list_5 = items.Filter(101);     //expect id : 11
    var list_6 = items.Filter(150);     //expect id : 11,13,14,17,18,19,20

}
```

Comment: Do you have *logical* (what algorithm?) problem or *implementation* (how to implement algorithm?) problem? I don't really understand what is *closest record*, to example, for `1000` it should be `900 + 100` (id: 11, 25), why do you expect it to be `100 + 300 + 600`?

Comment: var list_1 = items.Filter(1000);    //expect id : 11,12,16 you can also have, expected result is 12,13,14,16,21 => 1000. So you may another condition like the shortest array

Comment: @Sinatr is right.. how do you decide which value to pick ?

Comment: the data source is to irregular and the question is to vague to extrapolate the functionality of this said Filter method

Comment: priority is less id.

Comment: does it have to fit the number exactly or just get close?

Comment: if could exactly , not get closer.

Comment: i will give you an exact match and then you can extrapolate from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation of [0/1 Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem), which has a solution that is pseudo-polynomial in both space, which is O(k), and time, which is O(Tk), where `k` is the number of items, and `T` is the expected number.

The article linked above has simple pseudocode for solving the problem. You should modify it to use a pair of single-dimension arrays instead of a 2D array to conserve memory. This is possible, because each iteration references at most two rows in a 2D array - the one being constructed, and the one immediately in front of it.

The algorithm constructs an array of reachable totals. You can run the algorithm in reverse to extract the sequence of IDs that lead to the particular result for which you are filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to approach this in steps

1. Sort the list by value descending
2. Iterate over the list until you get to the first value equal to or less than the filter value
3. Create a list of the remaining items and group them together until the sum of grouped items equals or exceeds the filter value
4. Finally, check if the sum exceeds the filter value and if so remove the item with the smallest value
5. Continue the iteration until the list is empty or until you have an exact match

*Note: This is a simplistic implementation in the sense that it will get a close match instead of an exact match as follows:*

```
values: 3,5,7,9,11

filter value: 19

returns 11, 7 (total : 18)
```

A better algorithm would return `11, 5, 3 (total: 19)` but this would be more computationally expensive requiring multiple iterations of the values.

How important is accuracy in your scenario?